# Adding String with Recursive function in C

Tags: c, string, recursion, concatenation

I need to write a probram in C, which adds a string to a string etc. (for example '5' strings - It needs to read "vbvbvbvbvb" 5 times.) But it doesn't work? Help please!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char s[80];
int len;
int counter = 0;

char* repeat(char* s, int n) {

    if (n > 0) {
        if (s[len] == n) {
            counter++;
        }
        len--;
        repeat(s, (n++));
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", repeat("vb", 5));
    fflush(stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write into the end of `"vb"` which is a string in the constant pool.  Don't do that.  Allocate a string that is `strlen(s) * n + 1` long and write into that.

Your base case is probably wrong.  The base case should probably be when `n == 0` which is when the empty string (nothing appended except terminating NUL as below) is appropriate.

Your recursive step `(n++)` should probably be `(n - 1)` to count down to that base case.  As written, the post-increment does a useless assign and recurses with the same value of `n`.

I don't know what `counter` and `len` are supposed to do, but they looks redundant to me.  `len` is uninitialized, so `s[len]` has undefined behavior.

After writing the `n` copies, you need to add a terminating NUL (`'\0'`) at the end so that `printf` and similar functions can identify the end.

Comment: He doesn't write anything, does he?

Comment: @gnometorule, Ah.  I didn't even notice that, but it's obvious now that you mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using s both as a global and a local variable, the function is working on the local.
Try not to use global variables where not necessary.  Also, recursion is not necessary for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concatenate_string(char *dest, const char *src, int n) {

    char *s;
    while(n--) {
        s = (char*)src;
        while(*(s))
            *(dest++)=*(s++);           
    }
    *(dest++) = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char out[80];

    concatenate_string(out, "ab", 5);
    printf("%s", out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is necessary, because I have to do this for a school project.